# Fit Landscape Table on Portrait Page below Text

Tags: rotating, tabu

After a fair bit of trial and error, I managed to generate a LaTeX table and get it to display in landscape format on a portrait page.
However, it now fits the entire height, leaving the four "header" text lines above it on the previous page.

It may be due to my inexperience with LaTeX, but I have been unable to convince all of the below to fit on a single page.
I would very much appreciate any suggestions you might be able to give.

See below for the relevant parts of my source code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% GENERATE CAPTION
\newcommand{\AddCaption}[1]{
\textbf{#1}
\\ \\
}

% GENERATE TABLE
\newcommand{\FigureAddTable}[3]{
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0mm}
\begin {tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{2mm}}l}
 {#1} \\
 {#2} \\
 {#3}
\end {tabular*} \\
}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0mm}
\begin{document}

\begin {tabular}{p{\textwidth}}
  \AddCaption{ZERO SPEED TESTS IN IRREGULAR WAVES - FINS PASSIVE}
\FigureAddTable{Heading = 270 deg - H$_{\text{s}}$ =  1.0 m - T$_{\text{p}}$ =  6.5 s}{TEST NO. 403001}{}{}
\end {tabular}\\*

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabu}{| l | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] |}
  \hline
  \rowfont{\bfseries\itshape\large} Signal & Mean & StdDev & A1/3Max & A1/3Min & H1/3 & A1/10Max & A1/10Min & Max & Min & HMax & NOsc \\
  \hline
  WAVE1 [m] & -0.0 & 0.25 & 0.52 & -0.5 & 0.99 & 0.66 & -0.6 & 1.01 & -1.0 & 1.57 & 395 \\
  WAVE2 [m] & 0.01 & 0.26 & 0.57 & -0.5 & 1.06 & 0.73 & -0.6 & 1.09 & -0.8 & 1.72 & 411 \\
  SURGE LF [m] & 0.04 & 0.34 & 0.73 & -0.6 & 1.38 & 0.88 & -0.7 & 1.06 & -0.9 & 1.92 & 41 \\
  SURGE WF [m] & -8.0 & 0.01 & 0.02 & -0.0 & 0.04 & 0.02 & -0.0 & 0.04 & -0.0 & 0.07 & 342 \\
  SWAY LF [m] & -0.1 & 0.32 & 0.51 & -0.8 & 1.12 & 0.70 & -1.0 & 0.94 & -1.1 & 1.78 & 45 \\
  SWAY WF [m] & 6.94 & 0.16 & 0.33 & -0.3 & 0.64 & 0.41 & -0.4 & 0.56 & -0.5 & 1.09 & 334 \\
  HEAVE [m] & 0.00 & 0.24 & 0.50 & -0.4 & 0.97 & 0.63 & -0.6 & 0.86 & -0.8 & 1.61 & 352 \\
  ROLL [deg] & 0.11 & 0.64 & 1.44 & -1.1 & 2.70 & 1.79 & -1.5 & 2.09 & -2.0 & 4.11 & 1357 \\
  PITCH [deg] & -0.0 & 0.11 & 0.18 & -0.2 & 0.40 & 0.24 & -0.3 & 0.45 & -0.4 & 0.75 & 2406 \\
  YAW LF [deg] & 0.06 & 0.09 & 0.25 & -0.1 & 0.43 & 0.29 & -0.1 & 0.35 & -0.2 & 0.63 & 5156 \\
  YAW WF [deg] & -2.5 & 0.06 & 0.12 & -0.1 & 0.22 & 0.16 & -0.1 & 0.24 & -0.2 & 0.40 & 2486 \\
  AX UPDECK [$m/s^2$] & 0.00 & 0.06 & 0.13 & -0.1 & 0.25 & 0.17 & -0.1 & 0.24 & -0.2 & 0.49 & 411 \\
  AY UPDECK [$m/s^2$] & -0.0 & 0.31 & 0.60 & -0.6 & 1.19 & 0.77 & -0.8 & 1.07 & -1.0 & 1.98 & 292 \\
  AZ UPDECK [$m/s^2$] & 0.00 & 0.29 & 0.59 & -0.6 & 1.17 & 0.76 & -0.7 & 1.03 & -1.0 & 2.12 & 344 \\
  EGA UPDECK [deg] & -0.0 & 1.82 & 3.63 & -3.6 & 6.98 & 4.65 & -4.5 & 6.65 & -6.0 & 11.8 & 1678 \\
  AX BRIDGE [$m/s^2$] & 0.00 & 0.05 & 0.11 & -0.1 & 0.21 & 0.14 & -0.1 & 0.20 & -0.2 & 0.41 & 411 \\
  AY BRIDGE [$m/s^2$] & -0.0 & 0.30 & 0.57 & -0.6 & 1.14 & 0.73 & -0.7 & 0.97 & -0.9 & 1.85 & 292 \\
  AZ BRIDGE [$m/s^2$] & 2.58 & 0.31 & 0.61 & -0.6 & 1.21 & 0.78 & -0.8 & 1.05 & -1.1 & 2.17 & 347 \\
  EGA BRIDGE [deg] & -0.0 & 1.75 & 3.44 & -3.5 & 6.71 & 4.43 & -4.4 & 5.98 & -5.6 & 11.0 & 1661 \\
  AX AMIDPS [$m/s^2$] & -0.0 & 0.03 & 0.07 & -0.0 & 0.14 & 0.09 & -0.0 & 0.13 & -0.1 & 0.26 & 393 \\
  AY AMIDPS [$m/s^2$] & -0.0 & 0.27 & 0.52 & -0.5 & 1.05 & 0.66 & -0.7 & 0.89 & -0.9 & 1.70 & 296 \\
  AZ AMIDPS [$m/s^2$] & -0.0 & 0.30 & 0.59 & -0.6 & 1.20 & 0.76 & -0.8 & 1.01 & -1.1 & 2.17 & 342 \\
  EGA AMIDPS [deg] & -0.0 & 1.63 & 3.14 & -3.3 & 6.21 & 4.03 & -4.1 & 5.62 & -5.3 & 10.1 & 1695 \\
  AX AMIDSB [$m/s^2$] & 0.00 & 0.05 & 0.11 & -0.1 & 0.20 & 0.14 & -0.1 & 0.20 & -0.2 & 0.40 & 422 \\
  AY AMIDSB [$m/s^2$] & -0.0 & 0.27 & 0.52 & -0.5 & 1.05 & 0.66 & -0.7 & 0.89 & -0.9 & 1.70 & 296 \\
  AZ AMIDSB [$m/s^2$] & 0.00 & 0.29 & 0.59 & -0.5 & 1.16 & 0.76 & -0.7 & 1.06 & -1.0 & 2.09 & 348 \\
  EGA AMIDSB [deg] & -0.0 & 1.63 & 3.10 & -3.4 & 6.18 & 3.95 & -4.2 & 5.45 & -5.4 & 10.0 & 1695 \\
  AX AFTDCK [$m/s^2$] & 0.00 & 0.04 & 0.09 & -0.0 & 0.17 & 0.11 & -0.1 & 0.16 & -0.1 & 0.32 & 411 \\
  AY AFTDCK [$m/s^2$] & -0.0 & 0.27 & 0.50 & -0.6 & 1.03 & 0.64 & -0.7 & 0.91 & -0.9 & 1.69 & 308 \\
  AZ AFTDCK [$m/s^2$] & 0.00 & 0.29 & 0.57 & -0.6 & 1.15 & 0.74 & -0.7 & 1.00 & -1.1 & 2.11 & 354 \\
  EGA AFTDCK [deg] & -0.1 & 1.60 & 3.04 & -3.4 & 6.06 & 3.88 & -4.2 & 5.79 & -5.5 & 10.1 & 1770 \\
  \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{sidewaystable}
\clearpage

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like this?

[image]

so fa i made only tweo changes to your code:

- increase text area in your page layout (otherwice table not fit on page)
- change `sidewaystrable` to `sideways`

in next iteration of answer i will tryx to improve your table looks (what is off topic, of course):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
% GENERATE CAPTION
\newcommand{\AddCaption}[1]{
\textbf{#1}
\\ \\
}

% GENERATE TABLE
\newcommand{\FigureAddTable}[3]{
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0mm}
\begin {tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{2mm}}l}
 {#1} \\
 {#2} \\
 {#3}
\end {tabular*} \\
}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\begin {tabular}{p{\textwidth}}
  \AddCaption{ZERO SPEED TESTS IN IRREGULAR WAVES - FINS PASSIVE}
\FigureAddTable{Heading = 270 deg - H$_{\text{s}}$ =  1.0 m - T$_{\text{p}}$ =  6.5 s}{TEST NO. 403001}{}{}
\end {tabular}\\*

\begin{sideways}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\begin{tabu} to 0.8\textheight {| l | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] | X[c] |}
  \hline
  \rowfont{\bfseries\itshape\large} Signal & Mean & StdDev & A1/3Max & A1/3Min & H1/3 & A1/10Max & A1/10Min & Max & Min & HMax & NOsc \\
  \hline
  WAVE1 [m] & -0.0 & 0.25 & 0.52 & -0.5 & 0.99 & 0.66 & -0.6 & 1.01 & -1.0 & 1.57 & 395 \\
  WAVE2 [m] & 0.01 & 0.26 & 0.57 & -0.5 & 1.06 & 0.73 & -0.6 & 1.09 & -0.8 & 1.72 & 411 \\
  SURGE LF [m] & 0.04 & 0.34 & 0.73 & -0.6 & 1.38 & 0.88 & -0.7 & 1.06 & -0.9 & 1.92 & 41 \\
  SURGE WF [m] & -8.0 & 0.01 & 0.02 & -0.0 & 0.04 & 0.02 & -0.0 & 0.04 & -0.0 & 0.07 & 342 \\
  SWAY LF [m] & -0.1 & 0.32 & 0.51 & -0.8 & 1.12 & 0.70 & -1.0 & 0.94 & -1.1 & 1.78 & 45 \\
  SWAY WF [m] & 6.94 & 0.16 & 0.33 & -0.3 & 0.64 & 0.41 & -0.4 & 0.56 & -0.5 & 1.09 & 334 \\
  HEAVE [m] & 0.00 & 0.24 & 0.50 & -0.4 & 0.97 & 0.63 & -0.6 & 0.86 & -0.8 & 1.61 & 352 \\
  ROLL [deg] & 0.11 & 0.64 & 1.44 & -1.1 & 2.70 & 1.79 & -1.5 & 2.09 & -2.0 & 4.11 & 1357 \\
  PITCH [deg] & -0.0 & 0.11 & 0.18 & -0.2 & 0.40 & 0.24 & -0.3 & 0.45 & -0.4 & 0.75 & 2406 \\
  YAW LF [deg] & 0.06 & 0.09 & 0.25 & -0.1 & 0.43 & 0.29 & -0.1 & 0.35 & -0.2 & 0.63 & 5156 \\
  YAW WF [deg] & -2.5 & 0.06 & 0.12 & -0.1 & 0.22 & 0.16 & -0.1 & 0.24 & -0.2 & 0.40 & 2486 \\
  AX UPDECK [$m/s^2$] & 0.00 & 0.06 & 0.13 & -0.1 & 0.25 & 0.17 & -0.1 & 0.24 & -0.2 & 0.49 & 411 \\
  AY UPDECK [$m/s^2$] & -0.0 & 0.31 & 0.60 & -0.6 & 1.19 & 0.77 & -0.8 & 1.07 & -1.0 & 1.98 & 292 \\
  AZ UPDECK [$m/s^2$] & 0.00 & 0.29 & 0.59 & -0.6 & 1.17 & 0.76 & -0.7 & 1.03 & -1.0 & 2.12 & 344 \\
  EGA UPDECK [deg] & -0.0 & 1.82 & 3.63 & -3.6 & 6.98 & 4.65 & -4.5 & 6.65 & -6.0 & 11.8 & 1678 \\
  AX BRIDGE [$m/s^2$] & 0.00 & 0.05 & 0.11 & -0.1 & 0.21 & 0.14 & -0.1 & 0.20 & -0.2 & 0.41 & 411 \\
  AY BRIDGE [$m/s^2$] & -0.0 & 0.30 & 0.57 & -0.6 & 1.14 & 0.73 & -0.7 & 0.97 & -0.9 & 1.85 & 292 \\
  AZ BRIDGE [$m/s^2$] & 2.58 & 0.31 & 0.61 & -0.6 & 1.21 & 0.78 & -0.8 & 1.05 & -1.1 & 2.17 & 347 \\
  EGA BRIDGE [deg] & -0.0 & 1.75 & 3.44 & -3.5 & 6.71 & 4.43 & -4.4 & 5.98 & -5.6 & 11.0 & 1661 \\
  AX AMIDPS [$m/s^2$] & -0.0 & 0.03 & 0.07 & -0.0 & 0.14 & 0.09 & -0.0 & 0.13 & -0.1 & 0.26 & 393 \\
  AY AMIDPS [$m/s^2$] & -0.0 & 0.27 & 0.52 & -0.5 & 1.05 & 0.66 & -0.7 & 0.89 & -0.9 & 1.70 & 296 \\
  AZ AMIDPS [$m/s^2$] & -0.0 & 0.30 & 0.59 & -0.6 & 1.20 & 0.76 & -0.8 & 1.01 & -1.1 & 2.17 & 342 \\
  EGA AMIDPS [deg] & -0.0 & 1.63 & 3.14 & -3.3 & 6.21 & 4.03 & -4.1 & 5.62 & -5.3 & 10.1 & 1695 \\
  AX AMIDSB [$m/s^2$] & 0.00 & 0.05 & 0.11 & -0.1 & 0.20 & 0.14 & -0.1 & 0.20 & -0.2 & 0.40 & 422 \\
  AY AMIDSB [$m/s^2$] & -0.0 & 0.27 & 0.52 & -0.5 & 1.05 & 0.66 & -0.7 & 0.89 & -0.9 & 1.70 & 296 \\
  AZ AMIDSB [$m/s^2$] & 0.00 & 0.29 & 0.59 & -0.5 & 1.16 & 0.76 & -0.7 & 1.06 & -1.0 & 2.09 & 348 \\
  EGA AMIDSB [deg] & -0.0 & 1.63 & 3.10 & -3.4 & 6.18 & 3.95 & -4.2 & 5.45 & -5.4 & 10.0 & 1695 \\
  AX AFTDCK [$m/s^2$] & 0.00 & 0.04 & 0.09 & -0.0 & 0.17 & 0.11 & -0.1 & 0.16 & -0.1 & 0.32 & 411 \\
  AY AFTDCK [$m/s^2$] & -0.0 & 0.27 & 0.50 & -0.6 & 1.03 & 0.64 & -0.7 & 0.91 & -0.9 & 1.69 & 308 \\
  AZ AFTDCK [$m/s^2$] & 0.00 & 0.29 & 0.57 & -0.6 & 1.15 & 0.74 & -0.7 & 1.00 & -1.1 & 2.11 & 354 \\
  EGA AFTDCK [deg] & -0.1 & 1.60 & 3.04 & -3.4 & 6.06 & 3.88 & -4.2 & 5.79 & -5.5 & 10.1 & 1770 \\
  \hline
\end{tabu}
```

**edit:**

off-topic: see if you like to have the following changes in your table:

- use `S` column type integrated into `tabu` column `X`
- use small font in column headers
- use `caption` for table caption
- use `siunitx` for all units notation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=25mm]{geometry}          % <--- added
\usepackage[skip=1ex, font={bf}]{caption}   % <--- added
\usepackage{siunitx}                        % <--- added

\usepackage{tabu}
\newcolumntype Y{S[table-format=-1.2]}      % <--- added
\newcolumntype Z{S[group-four-digits=true,  % <--- added
                   table-format= 4.0]}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
\caption{ZERO SPEED TESTS IN IRREGULAR WAVES - FINS PASSIVE\newline
        \normalfont
Heading$ = \ang{270} - \mathrm{H}_{\mathrm{s}}
         = \SI{1.0}{m} - \mathrm{T}_{\text{p}}
         = \SI{6.5}{s}$ \newline  
TEST NO. 403001}

\bigskip
\centering
\begin{sideways}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{5pt}
\tabulinesep=2pt
\begin{tabu} to 0.9\textheight {| l | *{10}{Y |}
                                            Z |}
    \hline
\rowfont{\bfseries\itshape\small} 
Signal              & {Mean}    & {StdDev}  & {A1/3Max} & {A1/3Min} & {H1/3}
                    & {A1/10Max}& {A1/10Min}& {Max}     & {Min}     & {HMax} 
                    & {NOsc}    \\
  \hline
WAVE1 [\si{m}]      & -0.0      & 0.25      & 0.52      & -0.5      & 0.99 
                    & 0.66      & -0.6      & 1.01      & -1.0      & 1.57 
                    & 395       \\
WAVE2 [\si{m}]      & 0.01      & 0.26      & 0.57      & -0.5      & 1.06 
                    & 0.73      & -0.6      & 1.09      & -0.8      & 1.72 
                    & 411       \\
SURGE LF [\si{m}]   & 0.04      & 0.34      & 0.73      & -0.6      & 1.38 
                    & 0.88      & -0.7      & 1.06      & -0.9      & 1.92 
                    & 41        \\
SURGE WF [\si{m}]   & -8.0      & 0.01      & 0.02      & -0.0      & 0.04 
                    & 0.02      & -0.0      & 0.04      & -0.0      & 0.07 
                    & 342       \\
SWAY LF [\si{m}]    & -0.1      & 0.32      & 0.51      & -0.8      & 1.12 
                    & 0.70      & -1.0      & 0.94      & -1.1      & 1.78
                    & 45        \\
SWAY WF [\si{m}]    & 6.94      & 0.16      & 0.33      & -0.3      & 0.64 
                    & 0.41      & -0.4      & 0.56      & -0.5      & 1.09 
                    & 334       \\
HEAVE [\si{m}]      & 0.00      & 0.24      & 0.50      & -0.4      & 0.97 
                    & 0.63      & -0.6      & 0.86      & -0.8      & 1.61 
                    & 352       \\
ROLL [\si{deg}]     & 0.11      & 0.64      & 1.44      & -1.1      & 2.70 
                    & 1.79      & -1.5      & 2.09      & -2.0      & 4.11 
                    & 1357      \\
PITCH [\si{deg}]    & -0.0      & 0.11      & 0.18      & -0.2      & 0.40 
                    & 0.24      & -0.3      & 0.45      & -0.4      & 0.75 
                    & 2406      \\
YAW LF [\si{deg}]   & 0.06      & 0.09      & 0.25      & -0.1      & 0.43 
                    & 0.29      & -0.1      & 0.35      & -0.2      & 0.63 
                    & 5156      \\
YAW WF [\si{deg}]   & -2.5      & 0.06      & 0.12      & -0.1      & 0.22 
                    & 0.16      & -0.1      & 0.24      & -0.2      & 0.40 
                    & 2486      \\
AX UPDECK [\si{m/s^2}]  & 0.00  & 0.06      & 0.13      & -0.1      & 0.25 
                    & 0.17      & -0.1      & 0.24      & -0.2      & 0.49 
                    & 411       \\
AY UPDECK [\si{m/s^2}]  & -0.0  & 0.31      & 0.60      & -0.6      & 1.19 
                    & 0.77      & -0.8      & 1.07      & -1.0      & 1.98 
                    & 292       \\
AZ UPDECK [\si{m/s^2}]  & 0.00  & 0.29      & 0.59      & -0.6      & 1.17 
                    & 0.76      & -0.7      & 1.03      & -1.0      & 2.12 
                    & 344       \\
EGA UPDECK [\si{deg}]   & -0.0  & 1.82      & 3.63      & -3.6      & 6.98 
                    & 4.65      & -4.5      & 6.65      & -6.0      & 11.8 
                    & 1678      \\
AX BRIDGE [\si{m/s^2}]  & 0.00  & 0.05      & 0.11      & -0.1      & 0.21 
                    & 0.14      & -0.1      & 0.20      & -0.2      & 0.41 
                    & 411       \\
AY BRIDGE [\si{m/s^2}]  & -0.0  & 0.30      & 0.57      & -0.6      & 1.14 
                    & 0.73      & -0.7      & 0.97      & -0.9      & 1.85 
                    & 292       \\
AZ BRIDGE [\si{m/s^2}]  & 2.58  & 0.31      & 0.61      & -0.6      & 1.21 
                    & 0.78      & -0.8      & 1.05      & -1.1      & 2.17 
                    & 347       \\
EGA BRIDGE [\si{m/s^2}] & -0.0  & 1.75      & 3.44      & -3.5      & 6.71 
                    & 4.43      & -4.4      & 5.98      & -5.6      & 11.0 
                    & 1661      \\
AX AMIDPS [\si{m/s^2}]  & -0.0  & 0.03      & 0.07      & -0.0      & 0.14 
                    & 0.09      & -0.0      & 0.13      & -0.1      & 0.26 
                    & 393       \\
AY AMIDPS [\si{m/s^2}]  & -0.0  & 0.27      & 0.52      & -0.5      & 1.05 
                    & 0.66      & -0.7      & 0.89      & -0.9      & 1.70 
                    & 296       \\
AZ AMIDPS [\si{m/s^2}]  & -0.0  & 0.30      & 0.59      & -0.6      & 1.20 
                    & 0.76      & -0.8      & 1.01      & -1.1      & 2.17 
                    & 342       \\
EGA AMIDPS [deg]    & -0.0      & 1.63      & 3.14      & -3.3      & 6.21 
                    & 4.03      & -4.1      & 5.62      & -5.3      & 10.1 
                    & 1695      \\
AX AMIDSB [\si{m/s^2}]  & 0.00  & 0.05      & 0.11      & -0.1      & 0.20 
                    & 0.14      & -0.1      & 0.20      & -0.2      & 0.40 
                    & 422       \\
AY AMIDSB [\si{m/s^2}]  & -0.0  & 0.27      & 0.52      & -0.5      & 1.05 
                    & 0.66      & -0.7      & 0.89      & -0.9      & 1.70 
                    & 296       \\
AZ AMIDSB [\si{m/s^2}]  & 0.00  & 0.29      & 0.59      & -0.5      & 1.16 
                    & 0.76      & -0.7      & 1.06      & -1.0      & 2.09 
                    & 348       \\
EGA AMIDSB [\si{deg}]   & -0.0  & 1.63      & 3.10      & -3.4      & 6.18 
                    & 3.95      & -4.2      & 5.45      & -5.4      & 10.0 
                    & 1695      \\
AX AFTDCK [\si{m/s^2}]  & 0.00      & 0.04      & 0.09      & -0.0      & 0.17 
                    & 0.11      & -0.1      & 0.16      & -0.1      & 0.32 
                    & 411       \\
AY AFTDCK [\si{m/s^2}]  & -0.0  & 0.27      & 0.50      & -0.6      & 1.03 
                    & 0.64      & -0.7      & 0.91      & -0.9      & 1.69 
                    & 308       \\
AZ AFTDCK [\si{m/s^2}]  & 0.00  & 0.29      & 0.57      & -0.6      & 1.15 
                    & 0.74      & -0.7      & 1.00      & -1.1      & 2.11 
                    & 354       \\
EGA AFTDCK [\si{deg}]   & -0.1  & 1.60      & 3.04      & -3.4      & 6.06 
                    & 3.88      & -4.2      & 5.79      & -5.5      & 10.1 
                    & 1770      \\
  \hline
\end{tabu}
\end{sideways}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]